# Can ImageMagick define a clipping path using drawing primitives?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, clip, graphicsmagick

Using `SVG`, you can define a clipping path and then apply it when drawing a path. Can the same effect be achieved using `ImageMagick` command-line options?

The only way I have been able to do it is to create the clipping path as a separate file and use `-clip-mask` to apply it. Here's a contrived example that works:

```
convert -size 150x150 xc:none -draw "path 'M50,50 h50 v50 -h-50 z'" clip.png
convert -size 150x150 xc: -fill 'blue' -clip-mask clip.png \ 
        -draw "path 'h150,0 l-75,75 z" image.png
```

What I want to do is define the clip path in the same command as the drawing, ideally somethig like this:

```
convert -size 150x150 xc: -fill 'blue' \
        -clip-path  "path 'M50,50 h50 v50 -h-50 z'" \
        -draw "path 'h150,0 l-75,75 z" image.png
```

Which doesn't work. To try and avoid using  an intermediate file, I tried using a *stacked image* but that doesn't seem to work as a parameter (the below did not work either):

```
convert -size 150x150 xc: -fill 'blue' \
        -clip-mask \( -size 150x150 xc:none -draw "path 'M50,50 h50 v50 -h-50 z'" \) \
        -draw "path 'h150,0 l-75,75 z" image.png
```

This can be done succinctly with SVG - can the `ImageMagick` command-line do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create intermediate files using the `mpr` *pseudo format* like this:

```
convert \( -size 150x150 xc:none -draw "path 'M50,50 h50 v50 -h-50 z'" \
           -write mpr:clip \) +delete \
        -size 150x150 xc: -fill 'blue' -clip-mask mpr:clip \
        -draw "path 'h150,0 l-75,75 z" image.png
```

This uses `-write` to cause the clip image to be written immediately (otherwise it is *stacked* until the end of the command sequence). It's then removed from the stack with `+delete` (otherwise it'll also be written at the end of the command sequence). The `-clip-mask` then reads the pseudo-file.

The pseudo file `mpr` is *Magick Persistent Registry* and is documented [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).